# How to read all frames in video without stop by opencv

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

Iv' written this code to extract all frames from videos and save as  images.
But somehow VideoCapture.read() return false even though it didn't reach the end frame.

How can I fix it and read all frames?

I've tried catch exception but it returns nothing.

I've followed source code and found VideoCaputre.read() calls VideoCapture.grab and this called icap->grabFrame() but couldn't get details about icap->grabFrame().

python3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
Opencv 3.4.3
Google Colaboratory

Video info
'coded_width': 4000
'coded_height': 3000
'r_frame_rate': '30000/1001'
'avg_frame_rate': '30000/1001'

```py
import os
import ffmpeg
import json
import cv2
import sys


base_dir = './gdrive/My Drive/'
files = os.listdir(base_dir)    

# only videos
mp4s =[]
mp4s = [file for file in files if 'MP4' in file ]

# get metadata
file_list = []

for video in mp4s:
  video_dir = base_dir + '/' + video
  video_info = ffmpeg.probe(video_dir)
  time = video_info['streams'][0]['tags']['creation_time']
  slice_str = time.find('T')
  slice_end = time.find('.')

  file_list.append({
      'file_name':video,
      'start_rec':time[slice_str + 1:slice_end],
      'end_rec':video_info['streams'][0]['tags']['timecode'],
      'duration':video_info['streams'][0]['duration'],
      'nb_frames':video_info['streams'][0]['nb_frames'],
      'coded_width':video_info['streams'][0]['coded_width'],
      'coded_height':video_info['streams'][0]['coded_height'],
      'r_frame_rate':video_info['streams'][0]['r_frame_rate'],
      'avg_frame_rate':video_info['streams'][0]['avg_frame_rate']
  }) 

#sort by recording start time
list_sorted = sorted(file_list, key=lambda x:x['start_rec'])
print(list_sorted)

#opencv extract all frames and save as png
dir_path = base_dir + '/' + 'images'
basename ='intervention'
ext = 'png'
n = 0

for dic in list_sorted:
  print('start', dic['file_name'])
  video_path = base_dir + '/' + dic['file_name']
  cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_path)

  if not cap.isOpened():
    print('not opened')
    sys.exit()

  os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)
  base_path = os.path.join(dir_path, basename)

  digit = len(str(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))))


# below this code ret supposed to be true until the end frame but did't reach the end

  while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print('ret=', ret)
    print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES), '/', cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

    if ret:
      cv2.imwrite('{}_{}.{}'.format(base_path, str(n).zfill(digit), ext), frame)
      n += 1

    else:
      print('done', dic['file_name'])
      cap.release()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      break
```

this is returned

start GX010223.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 96.0
~
ret= True
96.0 / 96.0
ret= False
96.0 / 96.0
done GX010223.MP4
start GX010224.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 105.0
~
ret= True
105.0 / 105.0
ret= False
105.0 / 105.0
done GX010224.MP4

start GX010225.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX010225.MP4

start GX020225.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX020225.MP4

start GX030225.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX030225.MP4

start GX040225.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX040225.MP4

start GX050225.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX050225.MP4

start GX060225.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 539.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 539.0
ret= False
29.0 / 539.0
done GX060225.MP4

start GX010226.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 282.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 282.0
ret= False
29.0 / 282.0
done GX010226.MP4

start GX010227.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX010227.MP4

start GX020227.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX020227.MP4

start GX030227.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX030227.MP4

start GX040227.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 15960.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 15960.0
ret= False
29.0 / 15960.0
done GX040227.MP4

start GX050227.MP4
ret= True
1.0 / 2514.0
~
ret= True
29.0 / 2514.0
ret= False
29.0 / 2514.0
done GX050227.MP4

I've tried to check 'it's empty or not' by this code

```
while True:

      ret, frame = cap.read()
      print('ret=', ret)
      print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES), '/', cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
      cv2.imwrite('{}_{}.{}'.format(base_path, str(n).zfill(digit), ext), frame)
      n += 1

      if ret == False:
        if frame == None:
          print('done', dic['file_name'])
          cap.release()
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          break
```

but when cap.read() failed it return None object so it didn't work well.

Comment: videocapture.read will return false if your hard drive is slow, and thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
VideoCapture cap("your_video.avi");
if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
    return -1;

Mat frame;
while(1) // looply reading frames from the video file
{
    cap >> frame; // try to get an image frame

    if (frame.empty())
    {
        // reach to the end of the video file
        break;
    }
}
```

frame.empty() would solve your problem. its in c++, but could be same in python.

Comment: I've tried to check 'it's empty or not' by this code
```python
while True:
     
      ret, frame = cap.read()
      print('ret=', ret)
      print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES), '/', cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
      cv2.imwrite('{}_{}.{}'.format(base_path, str(n).zfill(digit), ext), frame)
      n += 1
      
      if ret == False:
        if frame == None:
          print('done', dic['file_name'])
          cap.release()
          cv2.destroyAllWindows()
          break
```

but when cap.read() failed it return None object so it didn't work well.

Comment: do i need to minimize filesize or add codes in opencv source to continue until read succeeded ?

is there any way others?